# php codeigniter авторизация пользователей

Tags: php

Пишу авторизацию пользователей на *codeigniter/php*.

Подскажите алгоритм авторизации.

Делаю вот так

```
$login = $this->input->post("login");
$password = $this->input->post("password");
$query = $this->db->get_where("users",
 array("user_name" => $login,"password" => $password));
if($query == TRUE) {echo "Успех"} else { echo "неверно"}
```

но конструкция не рабочая, подскажите правильный метод написания подобной вещи. Спасибо.

```
<form method="post" action="" class="auth-entry">
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Введите Ваш логин...">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите Ваш пароль">
    <input type="submit" value="Войти">
</form>
```

Comment: `$this->db->get_where` возвращает какой-то объект. Посмотрите в его пропертя, может там есть какое поле с количеством найденных записей.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($query->result()) {echo "Успех"} else { echo "неверно"}
```